# Inheritance, only use the properties of your base class instead of the derived one

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

I have the Following structure for my table and datarow:

```
Public Class MyDataTable(Of MyDataRowDerived)

Public Class MyDataRowBase(Of DataRow)
    Public Property MyDescription As String

Public Class MyDataRowDerived(Of MyDataRowBase)
  inherits MyDataRowBase
    Public overrides Property MyDescription As String
```

If i create a row from my Table it is of the type `MyDataRowDerived`but i don't want to use the overridden properties on it and just the plain ones as in the base class. and tried to achieve it this way:

```
Dim row As MyDataRowBase = CType(myTable.AddNew(), MyDataRowBase)
Dim retrievedDescription = row.MyDescription
```

I tough this way i would force the object to believe its just the base class but it is still using the properties from my devired class.

The description returned by my object is as it is implemented in the derived class, but i need the one from the base class

Solutions can be added in C# also, no problem with that ;)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that.

Comment: The whole point of inheritance is not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you're looking for.  Replacing the functionality of the base class is what overriding is all about.  You can access base class members from the derived class, but not from outside classes.

What you could do is add a new property to your derived class that exposes the base class functionality under a different name:

```
public class MyDataRowBase : DataRow
{
  public virtual string MyDescription { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataRowDerived : MyDataRowBase
{
  public override string MyDescription { ... }

  public string BaseMyDescription
  {
    get { return base.MyDescription; }
    set { base.MyDescription = value; }
  }
}
```

Then you could use `BaseMyDescription` if you want to access the value of the base property from an outside class.

It's fairly unusual to want to do something like this, though.  If you give some more information about what you're trying to accomplish, it's possible people might have some good suggestions.

Comment: this is what i'm gonna do :)

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what you are asking for *exactly*, but

if you have

```
public class Base {
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}

public class Deived : Base {
    public void SomeMethod() {
        this.SomeProperty; //It's the same property available in base class 

        /**If the base property is virtual and you overriden in Derived 
           write base.SomeProperty **/
    }
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: @Jeroen: As I wrote, you can use *base* keyword to access esplicitly base class members, even if you have already overriden them in derived.

Comment: It's not from in the derived object i need to call the property from the base class, but when the object of the derived class is created, i need to call it's property but get it undecorated by the derived class but straight from the base

Comment: @Jeroen: if you are asking aout a possibility of accessing the *same* overriden property that one time it returns derived value, another time it returns base value, it's not possible. You can achieve that with a funnction a parameter which describes which value (derived or based) has to be returned.

Comment: thanks, now i know it can't be done unfortunatly :( i'll have to mess up the code a bit to get what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

That wont happen, you cannot refer child from base.